# ORA-00947: not enough values when creating object in Oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle11g, occi

I created a new TYPE in Oracle in order to have parity between my table and a local c++ object (I am using OCCI interface for C++).

In the code I use

```
void insertRowInTable ()
  {

    string sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_T VALUES (:x)";

    try{
    stmt = con->createStatement (sqlStmt);
    ObjectDefinition *o = new ObjectDefinition ();

    o->setA(0);
    o->setB(1);
    o->setC(2);
    stmt->setObject (1, o);
    stmt->executeUpdate ();
    cout << "Insert - Success" << endl;
    delete (o);
    }catch(SQLException ex)
    {
       //exception code
    }
```

The code compiles, connects to db but throws the following exception

> Exception thrown for insertRow Error number: 947 ORA-00947: not enough
>   values

Do I have a problematic "sqlStmt"? Is something wrong with the syntax or the binding?

Of course I have already setup an environment and connection

```
 env = Environment::createEnvironment (Environment::OBJECT);
    occiobjm (env);
    con = env->createConnection (user, passwd, db);
```

Comment: What is `statement`? What does `MyObject` or the variable `o` have to do with your problem? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I added more code. The ObjectDefinition is produced by OTT and I want to store the serialized object in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many columns are in the table?  The error message indicates that you didn't provide enough values in the insert statement.  If you only provide a VALUES clause, all columns in the table must be provided.  Otherwise you need to list each of the columns you're providing values for:

```
string sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_T (x_col) VALUES (:x)";
```

Edit:
The VALUES clause is listing placeholder arguments.  I think you need to list one for each value passed, e.g.:

```
string sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_T (GAME_ID, VERSION) VALUES (:x1,:x2)"
```

Have a look at [occidml.cpp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96583/cciaadem.htm) in the Oracle OCCI docs for an example.

Comment: I have 17 columns and I set o->set... 17 times. All values are passed.

Comment: Interesting that I changed the statement to write to two column but did not work either:  string sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_T (GAME_ID, VERSION) VALUES (:x)";

Comment: Updated my answer.